# How can I charge an ASUS Transformer while connected to USB?

Tags: usb, charging, asus-eee-pad-transformer

Currently I'm developing with my Nexus S but would like to use Asus Transformer for that.

So far I figured that device won't charge from USB. And for me - I need to have it on USB for debugging while charged and ON all the time.

Is that even possible? How long device lives on battery when 100% on?

**EDIT**

I look at keyboard accessory and it looks good. It seems that I can charge and it will serve as a stand. But I'm not sure if USB in keyboard will work for debugging?

Comment: Dev questions are off-topic here so I modified the title, I think the core question is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Asus Eee Pad Transformer uses a USB 3.0 cable. I've seen noises elsewhere on the 'net that it will only charge on a USB 3.0 socket. This is likely associated with the extra power only available on USB 3.0.